# select .. where ... or from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help here i have this 2 tables :

```
table "clients"
+------+-------------+-----------+
   id  |  email      |  otherinfo|
+------+-------------+-----------+
   1   |test@ts.ts   |   .....   |
+------+-------------+-----------+
   2   |test2@.ts.ts |   ....    |
+------+-------------+-----------+

table "comptes"
+------+-------------+---------------+
   id  |  login      |   id_clients  | 
+------+-------------+---------------+
 1     |     test    | 1             |
+------+-------------+---------------+
 1     |     test2   | 2             |
+------+-------------+---------------+
 etc.  |    etc.     |       etc..   |
+------+-------------+---------------+
```

In my website when a user crate an account he give the information of both tables. So i want to test if LOGIN or EMAIL exist in the database before adding them, something like this

```
'select clients.email,comptes.login    
from clients,comptes     
where clients.email='test2@.ts.ts'
 or comptes.login ='test';
```

But this query  return empty result, i tired other combination but none give the right results .So what i am messing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a join at all to see if they exist.  The following query returns the id of any matching record:

```
select c.id, 'email' as matchtype
from clients c
where c.email = <email>
union all
select c.id, 'login' as matchtype
from comptes c
where c.login = <login>
```

This gives you the matching ids and tells you where the duplicates are appearing (if that is of interest).  If you just want a 0 or 1 flag to specify the existence of duplicates, do this:

```
select count(*) as numdups
from ((select c.id, 'email' as matchtype
       from clients c
       where c.email = <email>
      )
      union all
      (select c.id, 'login' as matchtype
       from comptes c
       where c.login = <login>
     )
    ) t
```

Comment: thanks, that worked very well, but the 2nd query return this error 'Every derived table must have its own alias'

Comment: @user1559104 . . . I'm not sure why that would be.  Do you have the final "t"?  I check on SQL Fiddle, and aliases are not even allowed before the union all.

Comment: i did remove the final "t", and i use mysql with phpmyadmin. anyway i used the first solution, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a JOIN to tell mysql how the data is related: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html

eg:

```
SELECT clients.email, comptes.login
  FROM clients 
  JOIN comptes ON clients.id = comptest.id_clients
 WHERE clients.email='test2@.ts.ts'
    OR comptes.login ='test';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifically identify your JOIN fields.  The comma-seperated join syntax is really poor to use (IMO) and can give unexpected results.  IN your cases it it trying to join both tables on both id columns.  So try this

```
SELECT clients.email, comptes.login
FROM clients INNER JOIN comptes on clients.id = comptes.id_clients
WHERE clients.email='test2@.ts.ts' OR comptes.login = 'test';
```

Note that in this case, you would return two rows since your WHERE clause will end up giving you both client id 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cl.email, co.login
FROM clients AS cl
    INNER JOIN comptes AS co ON cl.id = co.id_clients
WHERE cl.email =  'test2@.ts.ts' OR co.login = 'test'
```